# How do I format this date time?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var timeStamp = "2021-11-11 00:32:47.5220000"
---
timeStamp as LocalDateTime {format: "yyyy-mm-dd"}
```

I need the output date to be "2021-11-11"

I am very weak at date conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll have to convert the string representation of the date and time to a Date time. In this case, as the string contains the date and time without the timezone, it has to be converted to LocalDateTime.

Once the string representation is converted to a date and time data type, it can be converted back to string in the desired format.

You can use the following DataWeave expression as a reference to implement your solution:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var timeStamp = "2021-11-11 00:32:47.5220000"

fun strToLocalDateTime(dateTimeStr, format) = 
dateTimeStr as LocalDateTime {format: format}

fun formatLocalDateTime(dateTime, format) = 
  dateTime as String {format: format}

fun convertDateTimeFormats(dateTimeStr, fromFormat, toFormat) = 
formatLocalDateTime(strToLocalDateTime(dateTimeStr, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS"), "yyyy-MM-dd")

---
convertDateTimeFormats(timeStamp, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS", "yyyy-MM-dd")
```